# mongodb $map to get value based on the object type

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Consider I have a value like this

```
var objList= { BMW: { type: 1, code: 'BW' },
  BENZ: { type: 2, code: 'BN' },
  RR: { type: 3, code: 'RR' }, };
```

And in my collection, it was stored liked 1, 2 or 3( which is a type from the above constant).. How can I create a query to map and return **BN** if type query supplied to filter was **2**.

var objList is from my constants file

I have a long aggregate list, **hope that will not be useful to decide something here and I guess my questing is not related to any issue or application specific**.

```
// Aggregate
var aggregateList = [
  { $match      : matches             },
  { $unwind     : unwind              },
  { $group      : group1              },
  { $unwind     : unwind              },
  { $sort       : sort                },
  { $skip       : skip                },
  { $limit      : limit               },
];

var db_collections = Car.aggregate(aggregateList)
```

Comment: Is this constant object type to code also stored at mongodb level? If not and the expected result-set from aggregation query is not very large, you could try to map in JS with iteration `Array.map()`

Comment: It is not from mongodb level.. it is normal file. Is there any way to use Array.map with mongo without having separate map

Comment: Then, one course of action could be to explicitly stating type to code via conditionals (this can be tedious and verbose if constants are many) via likes of [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/). With a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) if original values are stored in an array,